# jquery asp.net datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I have issues using jquery datepicker. Can someone help me on this.
I am using asp.net core mvc application and trying to add a datepicker using jquery. 
Here is the code :
cshtml:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#BeginDate").datepicker();
    });
</script>
 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label asp-for="BeginDate" style="font-size:12px;width:150px;"></label>
                    <input asp-for="BeginDate" style="font-size:12px;width:250px;" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="BeginDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
model class:
[DisplayName("Begin Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Begin Date is Required")]
 public DateTime?BeginDate { get; set; }
```

I have the jquery script and css included in layout page. The above cshtml page is partial view. I am not getting a date picker, however i am getting default drop down. I want to remove that and put a datepicker so that users can edit the begin date.

Let me know incase if you further information is required.

Thanks
Krishna.

Comment: Did you look at the rendered HTML to verify it has that "BeginDate" id?

Comment: By "jquery script" can we also assume that includes both jQuery and  jQuery UI?

Comment: yes i have added jquery and jquery UI as well

Comment: Yes, i do see the id = begindate rendered when i inspect the webpage

Comment: then the case in `#BeginDate` is wrong or your comment does not consider that case has to match and must be unique on the page

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - Sorry i didnt get you. what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: `id="begindate"` and `id="BeginDate"` are two different id's and the selector has to match whatever that is.  You might also put the script tag after/at the end of the partial view although that should not be the issue here

Comment: @Sorry my bad, I mean i am able see id = "BeginDate". I will try to put the script tag at the end and try.

Comment: also check the page where the partial view is to ensure you have the layout defined

Comment: its started working after putting the script tag after the partial view.